# Marketing Mix Modelling with industry-specific dataset from siMMMulator

Tags: r, facebook, machine-learning, regression

I want to create a case study with siMMMulator to test different marketing mix modelling (MMM) techniques that can be found online (LightweightMMM from Google, Robyn from Meta, etc.).
Is there a way to include in siMMMulator any industry-specific variables or ways to make the dataset generated industry-specific?

I already looked at siMMMulator in github but could not find an answer.
Thank you!!